# Strange usage of pointer and method

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

```
if (mySharedState -> liveIPs -> find(flowStats -> destinationIP) != mySharedState -> liveIPs -> end() ){
     //do something
}
```

`unordered_map <uint32_t, std::string> *liveIPs;`

I have never seen such a usage(usage of **find(...)** and **end()**). Could somebody help me about what it returns? 
(this is c++ code by the way)

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and you'll see why.

Comment: I can see what find method does. what you send is not what i m asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use this technique to check if the container contains that value.

`find()` returns an iterator corresponding to that value, `end()` returns an iterator 1 past the end of the container, which is used to signal "value not found".

Comment: Yeah, I can see that but I m asking for what it returns, a boolean value?

Comment: @tusherity Read that again: "find() returns an **iterator**"

Comment: @tusherity It is essentially `a != b` which returns a bool. (a == find(), b == end())

Comment: @tusherity the methods return iterators, the comparison of the iterators returns a boolean...

Comment: I think it returns iterator. But in that case SharedState should have that function, isnt it?

Comment: @tusherity what function? Note that the call is on `mySharedState -> liveIPs`, not on `mySharedState`. And `liveIPs` is an `unordered_map`, which does have those functions.

Comment: ohh, i see. This was exactly my problem. Thanks Luchian Grigore

Comment: I have one more question. Why `mysharedState -> liveIPs -> find(..)` used instead of `mysharedState -> liveIPs.find(..)`?

Answer (score 1):

Functions find(value) and end() are member functions of classes called "containers" used to store elements of various types (list, set, vector, map...). There is more info on containers [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

Both member functions return an iterator (kind of a pointer) to the container element. You can read about the iterators [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/).

Abstractly speaking, find(value) will give you the position of the element in a container that is equal to the value. And end() will return an iterator pointing to the end of the container (the position behind the last element).

So in your case:

```
// from mSharedState get liveIPs (a container storing IPs)
// and find the element with value destinationIP
mSharedState->liveIPs->find(flowStats->destinationIP) 

// check if the iterator returned by find(flowStats->destinationIP) is different
// then the end of the liveIPs contatiner
!= liveIPs->end()
```

So, "//do something" will be executed if the container liveIPs holds the element with the value destinationIP.

Since find(value) and end() are usually member functions of a container, I think that the code snippet you are showing is a part of the definition of a member function of a STL conformant container (maybe some user defined container that conforms to the STL container interface, providing find(value) and end() as member functions).